# Merge "htc-droid-incredible-2" and "htc-incredible-s"

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

The [Wikipedia page for the Incredible 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Droid_Incredible_2) simply redirects to the "Incredible S", where it states:

> The HTC Incredible S (S710E), also known as the Incredible 2, is a smartphone [...]

So quite obviously, the devices are identical. Hence my suggestion to merge [htc-droid-incredible-2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc-droid-incredible-2) (× 9) with [htc-incredible-s](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc-incredible-s) (× 12), preferably making the latter the master (as it already has a complete tag wiki) and the former, optionally, a synonym.

Comment: One is CDMA, the other is GSM.  If they are different phones I see no reason to merge them.

Comment: Sure? The Wikipedia page reads otherwise: *and it is a world phone able to access **both GSM and CDMA** networks* -- which to me sounds like "it's the same phone, and it can deal with both network types". So either Wikipedia has this wrong, or at least not clear? GSMArena OTOH supports what you wrote ?-/ So if you're sure about that, it seems to be the same as with the *Motorola Droid* vs. *Milestone*...

Comment: I generally go with GSMArena, PDADB and Jawal123 show the same.  XDA also has separate forums for them.  [Verizon's docs](http://cache.vzw.com/multimedia/mim/droid_incredible_2/incredible2.pdf) say that the CDMA version has a SIM so presumably it is a world phone like you say ... the question is whether the Incredible S is also a world phone and not purely GSM like the above sites say.  `"incredible s" cdma` isn't returning useful Google results for me.

Comment: I already accepted your argument (because of GSMArena), and set up the Incredible-2 tag wiki accordingly yesterday. Thanks for clarification, Matthew! I'd say just set this request to 'status-declined' (and the Milestone one as well, maybe), so it/they disappear(s) from the watchlists :)

Comment: Alright, will do :)